# "An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When going here:  right-click on my project > Properties > Android the below error happens.

[image: lkj]

This error happens when I go to Properties > Android on the project or either of the libraries (ignore BibleTriviaPro).

This error seems to have came out of nowhere.  I cannot think of anything I have changed and now all of a sudden tonight this error comes up.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Hii,,, i cant see the image.. can you give me some info..

Comment: The error says "Unable to create the selected property page.  An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (818)".  That is all that the picture shows.

Comment: This can also happen due to the JDK versioning as it did for me

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I was having the same error this morning strange as everything was fine last night.

Try cleaning all projects in workspace then restart eclipse - worked for me

Comment: Needed another clean after the restart, but that seems to fix the problem

Comment: For me worked this way: restart, clean, restart, clean, restart

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help - eclipse market place - search for adt. Then update or install it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error after updating the Android SDK and Eclipse ADT when opening a new workspace I created just before the update (where I deleted all projects after the update.) The solution for me was to load another workspace I got containing projects and then load the new workspace again.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse seems to search the same folder for 'sdk' , so I put sdk folder back in the same folder as Eclipse's. and problem solved.