# Cannot create new Android application project or access Android preferences using Eclipse Kepler

Tags: android, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Eclipse Keplar.When I try to create a new Android application project the following message is displayed:

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (241).

I cannot access the Window->Preferences->Android page,when I try the following message is displayed:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occured while automatically activating bundle.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.

No updates for the ADT plugin or the Android SDK were found.

What should I do to restore the ADT plugin to good working order?
Thanking You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this same problem today running a Windows 7 machine.  It has been a while since this question has been asked, but having an answer here might prove useful since this thread is ranking highly on Google for the error message:

I found that cleaning all projects in Eclipse and restarting it once it was finished solved the issue and I was able to successfully create a new Android project afterwards.

Eclipse menu: Project >> Clean

[image]

[Similar problem/answer found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974349/an-error-occurred-while-automatically-activating-bundle-com-android-ide-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

From console, run `eclipse -clean` (you'll need to make sure eclipse binary is in your PATH, or use full path to the binary).