# Android preferences error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, preferences

I have an eclipse juno release.

When I try to access the preferences (under Window - Preferences) then Android, the preference page displays the message "An error has occurred when creating this preference page."

I also get a 'Problem Occurred' dialogue displaying the following:-

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.idle.eclipse.adt (255).

I don't know what causes this problem!

Comment: [Clean + Restart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17060073/645270). Cause unknown.

Comment: i don't wanna to be rude but have searched in Google before asking this question.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8

Comment: I am sorry that my question bothered you,but actually I searched google before posting the question and didn't find the same exact error.If you are that annoyed,you are not obliged to answer any question:) Apart from that the restart worked fine,but you have to work more on your poor attitude.Respect!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error message in a prompt right after eclipse loaded, you should do the following:

1. Go to Help - Install new software
2. Click on Available software sites
3. Delete the link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Reboot eclipse
5. Go to Help - Install new software
6. In the box "Work with" add http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ again
7. Install ADT and accept whatever that prompts.

This is how my problem with this message got solved.