# Building workspace has encountered prob in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

When I try to open android project in eclipse indigo its showing following error but for first time it worked properly :

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class          com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class c   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1043).
```

Any idea a appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974349/an-error-occurred-while-automatically-activating-bundle-com-android-ide-eclipse)

Comment: @Neerav Shah I had the same problem for two times. At first time I downloaded ADT again and worked fine with. Hope this is bad idea.For urgency I did like that. Still I am searching for that. Once I found will let us know.

Comment: try switching the workspace  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33209027/4260932